# How to DISABLE Alexa's "holiday surprise protection"

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

I'm in the US, and our Alexas now refuse to tell us what's in our upcoming deliveries "to avoid spoiling any holiday surprises."  This is infuriating... it's one thing if it's a setting that can be simply disabled, but I can't find any way to do that.  We are a family of two humans who order everything through a single Amazon account anyway, so spoiling surprises is a complete non-issue.  We want to hear what's in our upcoming deliveries (for that matter, it's annoying Alexa will only tell us one item!).

Is there any way to override this "feature" that has been forced upon us?

Comment: If you search the web for `alexa surprise spoiler`, a setting in Lists comes up, maybe that could be related?

Comment: Sadly no, that's so you can enable this feature all year-round if you so choose.  I already have it disabled... but it's being forced on for the holidays.